# About accessing the Value of a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

This is a noob question, I know but I didn't find the answer on the internet...

I got the following Dictionary :

```
private static Dictionary<Qb.Solution.QbDataStore.DataStoreType, string> DataStoreType2IconPath = new Dictionary<QbDataStore.DataStoreType, string>()
{
    { Qb.Solution.QbDataStore.DataStoreType.CommonData, "Common" },
    { Qb.Solution.QbDataStore.DataStoreType.ApplicationData, "Application" },
    { Qb.Solution.QbDataStore.DataStoreType.FrameData, "Frame" }
};
```

and then I have a method with a `Qb.Solution.QbDataStore.DataStoreType dataType` parameter and I got this :

```
if (dataType != null)
{
    collection.IconPath = DataStoreType2IconPath[dataType];
}
```

My question is :

If I remove the `if` test, and that I don't know how (theorytically impossible) dataType is null :

1. collection.IconPath is null ?
2. it throw an exception ?

Comment: Try it and see? If you provide a non-null key that isn't in the dictionary, you get an exception.

Comment: It should throw an exception. Can't you try that?

Comment: you should always in my opinion have null checking because it's better to check than to assume.. also what type of Error/exception handling / checking are you planning to use wrap a Try Catch around your dataType != null if statement

Comment: Couldnt try in my main project but I could in a separate project, you're right... :( And sometimes posting here bring some light on a point I wasnt even thinking about :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my quick test, adding a null key to a dictionary causes an `ArgumentNullException` and trying to retrieve a key that doesn't exist results in a `KeyNotFoundException`.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication46
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            d.Add(null, 1);

            Console.WriteLine(d["adam"]);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

As for code reviewing how best to write it, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Alternative methods include `TryGetValue` and `ContainsKey`.

Answer (score 3):

It will throw an exception, so you're better with the if test.

You can also do it with the TryGetValue : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb347013.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you try to retrieve an entry from a dictionary which is not present a `KeyNotFoundException` is thrown, see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx). If this is not your desired behaviour use the [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) method instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, you cannot add a null key to a Dictionary -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx

You might want to check if the key exists using the ContainsKey() method rather than use TryGetValue or catching an exception. (You'll still need an if statement with TryGetValue, and best not to program using exceptions for logic if you can help it.)

```cs
if (DataStoreType2IconPath.ContainsKey(dataType))
{
    collection.IconPath = DataStoreType2IconPath[dataType];
}
```

If you *really* want to avoid the if statement, you could use the conditional operator:

```cs
collection.IconPath = DataStoreType2IconPath.ContainsKey(dataType) ?
                        DataStoreType2IconPath[dataType] : null;
```

Personally I prefer this "expression" style of programming rather than statements, but that's just me. :-)